Is there any efficient way to download selected secrets from a common Azure Key Vault of an organization?
I have a shared Azure Key Vault instance that contains a large number of secrets for various applications within our platform. My requirement is to efficiently retrieve only the secrets relevant to my specific application which will be only around 10 secrets out of 5000 secrets.
Currently, I’m using the following code to fetch and filter the secrets:
//code to get all secrets from that keyvault 
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetKeys()
{
    var keyVaultSecureValueManager = (KeyVaultSecureValueManager)this.SecureValueManager;
    var allPages = keyVaultSecureValueManager.Client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync().AsPages();

    await foreach (var page in allPages)
    {
        foreach (var secretProperties in page.Values)
        {
            yield return secretProperties.Name;
        }
    }
}

//filter locally, the required keys alone.
 private static async Task<List<string>> GetKeysAsync(IAsyncEnumerable<string> keyvaultKeys)
    {
        List<string> keys = new List<string>();
        await foreach (var key in keyvaultKeys)
        {
            if (key.StartsWith("myKeys", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                keys.Add(key);
            }
        }

        return keys;
    }

 //get individual secret
 private async Task<KeyVaultResponse> GetCertAsync(string key)
    {
        return await secretManager.GetKeyAsync(key);
    }


 //code get secret value of selected secrets from the all secrets properties
 public async Task<Certs> GetAllCertsAsync()
    {
        var keyvaultKeys = this._secretManager.GetKeys();
        var selectedKeys = await GetKeysAsync(keyvaultKeys);
        var allCertKeys = selectedKeys.Where(s => s.EndsWith("cert", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        var allPwdKeys = selectedKeys.Where(s => s.EndsWith("pwd", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        // Fetch all certificates concurrently
        var fetchTasks = allCertKeys.Select(c => this.GetCertAsync(c, allPwdKeys));
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(fetchTasks);

        // Check for any bad requests
        var badRequest = results.FirstOrDefault(res => res.IsBadRequest);
        if (badRequest != null)
        {
            return BadRequestResponse(badRequest.ErrorMessage);
        }

        return results;
    }

This approach results in numerous roundtrips to the server as it downloads all secret properties and then filters them locally. This is causing performance bottlenecks, especially given the volume of secrets in the Key Vault.
Is there a way to reduce the number of server roundtrips by applying server-side filtering when retrieving secrets with SecretClient in the Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets namespace?
Are there any recommended practices for organizing secrets within a shared Azure Key Vault to make retrieval more efficient? For example, grouping secrets by application or domain to allow querying a specific collection or group.
I’m looking for concrete guidance or code examples to address these issues and avoid common anti-patterns. My application is a Web API deployed on AKS.

Your code deals with "Keys" when you ask about grouping "Secrets." However, these two terms are different in the context of Key Vault. Which one are you trying to group per app?

@Artem, let me give more context before getting to your question, now our keyvault instance in-use is common one & it is used by 100's of domains. Now my question is, within that same keyvault instance, is there possibility  to create internal groups where each group can holds secrets/keys for each specific domain, so if an application wants to download all its secret, it only then query group of secret specific to the specific domain with bothering about other groups belongs to other domains?

If the goal is just to organize secrets in a key vault, you can use tags (with application names, for example). However, this does not help solve the performance bottleneck, as the Key Vault's REST Api doesn't support filtering by tags.
I recommend considering App Configuration in conjunction with the Key Vault reference feature. App Configuration supports labels (similar to Key Vault's tags) and supports filtering by labels. In other words, your app can read only secrets marked with a specific label(-s) and/or unlabelled secrets.
builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
    {
            options.Connect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConfig"))
                .Select(KeyFilter.Any, "app1")
                .Select(KeyFilter.Any, LabelFilter.Null);
    });

The huge benefit of using App Configuration is its C# middleware that implements caching under the hood and would solve your performance concerns.
Let me emphasize that your secrets will remain in the key vault. App Configuration will be only a proxy between the consuming app and the Key Vault (see a picture below).


this doesn't work for us, as we use AKS for deployment & secrets on KV, where KV doesn't support server side filtering beyond getsecretbyname so you end up in downloading allsecretproperties on client then perform local filtering which kills the performance, any suggestion to overcome this particular step?


Any recommended practice to group the secrets per app specific or domain specific with in the common Azure key vault instance, so just to query that collection or group alone to improve efficiency?

You can use a prefix for your secrets based on the app or domain, e.g. myapp_cosmosdb_connection_string or mydomain_redis_connection_string. Or, as an alternative, use tags as recommended by Artem.

As per our analysis async IAsyncEnumerable GetKeys() makes hundreds of roundtrips to the server as it has to download all those tons of secrets properties from server. Any way you we can avoid those many unwanted round trips? by doing server side filter using any Azure key vault SDKs?

I'm not sure if there is any sort of "server-side filtering", but as a starting point and to keep it simple maybe try reading all secrets from the keyvault and use in-memory cache to avoid the round trips and consequently other issues such as throttling limits?
